# Changing the color of a jQuery Mobile Select menu

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm looking to change the color of a Select Menu, now this needs to be done with CSS. As the page loads the color is off all I need to do is change its color on the element, I dont need any javascript etc this is just for this element. Now I've inspected the element:

The Jquery Mobile adds this random div in the page as shown in the picture below:

[image]

When the inspector is open I can change the color of the select menu by adding the style (See picture)

[image]

Now this works but I want to know how to do this change permanently using css. I'm using the following:

```
div#select-choice-1-button.ui-btn .ui-icon-carat-d .ui-btn-icon-right .ui-corner-all .ui-shadow
        {
            color: #323232 !important;
        }
```

I got the css from the inspector as seen at the bottom of the screen. However when I use this the select menu still remains white. I've got no idea how to fix this...

Comment: For that selector to work you would have to remove all of the spaces. eg, `div#select-choice-1-button.ui-btn.ui-icon-carat-d.ui-btn-icon-right.ui-corner-all.ui-shadow {`

Comment: ... but using this would be a bad idea anyway because JQM will add those classes to other elements too.

Comment: aaaaaaa so many hours wasted. Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to do it by the ID of that div that JQM adds. So something like this `#select-choice-1-button span { color: #323232;} should do the trick. `